# deploying to heroku, getting error

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, socket.io, mean

Im trying to deploy on Heroku using command git push heroku master but I run into following issue :

[click here to see error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4qFw.png)

[ending logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9m7i.png)

Below is error

```
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
```

Comment: Looks like the build worked, its an error in the app you deployed. If you look in your runner logs and see what it says in there.

Comment: NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

Comment: Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: Logs are made of _text_. They should be shared _as text_, not as screenshots. Text can be copied and pasted into a text editor! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be efficiently searched! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be consumed by users of assistive technologies, like screenreaders! Screenshots cannot :-(. Please give text the respect it deserves instead of banishing it to inaccessible image formats.

Comment: @YOGEESH, your build worked fine. Your _application_ is crashing. Please run `heroku logs` and edit your question to add the output of that command _as text_. After pasting you can select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to indent the block and treat it as code.